# Confusion with GWT, Native, Hybrid, Web and their Datastorage

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I told my tutor i will make Native Apps. But After making the android project on Eclipse. I am stuck
wondering where i should store my data online. I heard Google App Engine is free but after some research   it turns out the Google app engine only allows web apps to store with their Google Web toolkit.

I'm hoping to use a free online data storage for the native app I have created. I was trying to use JSON but now I'm completely lost.

Can someone provide me some details how to store native apps online for free?
They don't have to be in detail just to clear my head please.

Comment: i have looked at this https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/ but im not sure if this is what i need.

Comment: "only allows web apps to store with their Google Web toolkit." No. GWT apps can store there, yes, but everything else can too. AppEngine (like several similar services) is also just free until you hit a certain limit. It's reasonably high so small apps are in fact free.

Comment: Do you know a way i can store to GAE using eclipse and Json. I find it very difficult to add app engine onto eclipse unlike the GWT that comes with it. I want to add app engine and get started with just a basic app i created. Can you give me any tips or links to tutorials i have being up all night googling no hope so far.

Comment: The link you posted is what you need. You'll also find more tutorials when you search for "clound endpoints", e.g. http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/ (no idea what's better)

Comment: Depending on your need, you may not have to develop a full cloud back-end (which can do way more than just storing data - you can process the data on the server too), there are simpler ways of more or less just storing data, for example https://parse.com/docs/android_guide or https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html